# raise function causing SyntaxError when short coding in python3.x by Boolean Expressions

Tags: python-3.x

It's ok when:

`>>> 1>0 and print('y')
y`

But, it cause SyntaxError when:

`>>> 1>0 and raise MyErr('This is an error',1)
File "<stdin>", line 1
1>0 and raise MyErr('This is an error',1)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Why? Can anyone help me to clear up this confusion?

p.s it's worked when `if 1>0: raise MyErr('This is an error',1)`

Comment: Is `MyErr` defined? Why is there a `^` symbol?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the `^` symbol was in inaccurate arrangement and  I re-edited the question to make it clear. and MyErr is defined and it worked when:`if 1>0: raise MyErr('This is a error',1)`.

Comment: Well, did you define `MyErr` ? There is no error known as `MyErr` unless you create it.

Comment: the question is solved by Mike. and thank you for sparing your precious time answering my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raise` is a statement and has to be first on a line. This works:

```
raise 1 > 0 and MyErr('This is a error', 1)
```

This does not work:

```
1 > 0 and raise MyErr('This is a error', 1)
```

This is different:

```
if 1 > 0: 
    raise MyErr('This is a error', 1)
```

Here `raise` is first on its line. The proper use of a statement.